# IO Error: Socket read timed out. What are the reasons?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

My simplified code (which demonstrates that the connection breaks with error "IO Error: Socket read timed out"):

```
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@", properties);
    while(isStarted){
        this.statement = this.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = this.statement.executeQuery("select sysdate from dual");
        result.next();
        System.out.println("Sysdate: " + result.getString(1));
        result.close();
        this.statement.close();
        this.statement = null;
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
    }
    this.connection.close();
    this.connection = null;
```

after 4-5 hours i catched:

```
 IO Error: Socket read timed out
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:886)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1491)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)
```

What are the reasons? how to solve this problem?

Comment: There is only one reason. The database didn't respond within the timeout period. Why on earh are you doing this non-event in a loop at all?

Comment: My simplified code (which demonstrates that the connection breaks with error "IO Error: Socket read timed out"). I connect only one time, and after that use connection everywere.

Comment: What is the connectivity to the database? A socket read timeout /can/ indicate that the socket connection was silently terminated. This is more common when a vpn and/or firewalls are in play.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Check your services and see to it that only OracleServiceXE and Oracle XETNSListener is running.

You can crosscheck it in cmd by using command

> netstat -ano | find "1521"

In the result the last column shows the PID and it should be unique. If the command returns no result then your Listener is not running.